# Expectation value - does it need to be on a Banach space?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I came across the following definition of a exception value of a random variable $X$ in (Lord, Powell and Shardlow, 2014;pg139; emphasis not mine):

> Let $X$ be a Banach space-valued random variable on the probability
>   space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\Bbb{P})$. If $X$ is integrable, the
>   *expectation* of the $X$ is $$\Bbb{E}[X]:= \int_\Omega X(\omega)d\Bbb{P}(\omega), \tag{4.1}$$

Why is there a resection to Banach space-random variables here? Why won't only old measurable space do?

Comment: It's Banach-space *valued*, it's still defined on a normal probability space.

Comment: So we think of this $X$ as a "random element" of the Banach space.  Just as an ordinary random variable is a "random real number".

Comment: @1524 I know, but from the definitions I have seen random variables go from measurable spaces to probability spaces.

Comment: to define a $L_1$ function and thus expectation  you need a norm.

Comment: @GEdgar I know the meaning of Banach space-valued rvs, that is not my question. I am concerned with the fact that we are restricting the definition of a exception value to only Banach space-valued rvs and not open to all random elements.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Oh ok, that makes sense. Though in theory does it not need to be a Banach space and a measurable space for the above definition to hold? (see my comment to '1524' above)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I am not sure I see the reasoning in this question? I agree with you that our rv must be over a Banach-vector space to define a function to be integral - thanks for making me away of this. My concern now is that from the definition of an rv we need this Banach space to also be a measurable space.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood. You use the borel sigma algebra on the Banach space

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two objects being considered here - the *sample space* $\Omega$, and an unnamed *state space* which I shall call $E$, which in this case is assumed to be a Banach space. (It is fairly unhelpful that the author does not give the state space a name, and probably contributes to your confusion.) Our random variable is $X:\Omega\to E$.

Random variables need not take values in Banach spaces. Indeed, at its most basic definition, a random variable is just a measurable map from a probability space to a measurable space. However, for almost all practical purposes, we require some topology on the state space. Do you want any kind of notion of convergence? Then you need some kind of topology.

(Edit, to make something clear from the comments: whenever you have a topological space, you also have a measurable space by considering the Borel $\sigma$-field. Unless otherwise specified, you should always assume this is the $\sigma$-field considered when we have a topological space being considered in measure/probability theory.)

In this case, we are looking at the expectation of a random variable, which we know is simply the integral of the measurable function $X$. But what is the integral? Any definition of an integral requires linear combinations and limits, so at the least we will require $E$ to be a topological vector space. Assuming $E$ is Banach simply makes things a little cleaner - the topology of a normed vector space is easier to understand, and making it complete (i.e. Banach) merely guarantees that the space possesses enough limits to avoid running into problems.